# javascript function call frequency counter

Tags: javascript, uml, cocos2d-js

I have a mobile game written in cocos2d-js (c++ && javascript && spidermonkey).

Now the game performance is not that good so I'm trying to do some code-level optimization.

One thing I want to do is to record the data of "how many times each functions have been called during game time". (it's a mobile game so I can not run it in browser)

But, it will be impossible to add code for all the functions so I'm trying find a good way to get thing done.

And still, I'm wondering if there is any tools that can generate UML diagrams from javascript source code such as class diagrams, function reference diagram, etc.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You can use [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) to `instrument` your code.